# Cannot initialize the indexer process after changing the price scope in catalog configuration

Tags: magento-1.8

I'm getting the famous "cannot initialize indexer process" while indexing the prices. 
In the log I get the below error.
This error appeared after that I changed in System->Configuration->Catalog->Price the scope to website and then back to global.

What I tryed so far:
- flush cache
- removing all the products in catalog
- readding the products in catalog

Have no idea how to solve this.

```
014-03-08T00:10:43+00:00 DEBUG (7): Exception message: SQLSTATE[21S01]: Insert value   list does not match column list: 1136 Column count doesn't match value count at row 1
Trace: #0 /u01/www/cellxpressions.net/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110):  Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 /u01/www/cellxpressions.net/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 /u01/www/cellxpressions.net/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(479): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 /u01/www/cellxpressions.net/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `sm...', Array)
#4 /u01/www/cellxpressions.net/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(428): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `sm...', Array)
5 /u01/www/cellxpressions.net/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Indexer/Price.php(455): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('INSERT INTO `sm...')
#6 /u01/www/cellxpressions.net/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Indexer/Price.php(379): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Indexer_Price->_prepareTierPriceIndex()
#7 /u01/www/cellxpressions.net/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Indexer/Abstract.php(143): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Indexer_Price->reindexAll()
#8 /u01/www/cellxpressions.net/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(210): Mage_Index_Model_Indexer_Abstract->reindexAll()
#9 /u01/www/cellxpressions.net/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(258): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexAll()
#10 /u01/www/cellxpressions.net/app/code/core/Mage/Index/controllers/Adminhtml/ProcessController.php(182): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexEverything()
#11 /u01/www/cellxpressions.net/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Index_Adminhtml_ProcessController->massReindexAction()
#12 /u01/www/cellxpressions.net/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('massReindex')
#13 /u01/www/cellxpressions.net/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#14 /u01/www/cellxpressions.net/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#15 /u01/www/cellxpressions.net/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#16 /u01/www/cellxpressions.net/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#17 {main}
```

The query which is causing the crash is:

```
INSERT INTO `sm_catalog_product_index_tier_price` SELECT `tp`.`entity_id`, `cg`.`customer_group_id`, `cw`.`website_id`, MIN(IF(tp.website_id = 0, ROUND(tp.value * cwd.rate, 4), tp.value)) FROM `sm_catalog_product_entity_tier_price` AS `tp` INNER JOIN `sm_customer_group` AS `cg` ON tp.all_groups = 1 OR (tp.all_groups = 0 AND tp.customer_group_id = cg.customer_group_id) INNER JOIN `sm_core_website` AS `cw` ON tp.website_id = 0 OR tp.website_id = cw.website_id INNER JOIN `sm_catalog_product_index_website` AS `cwd` ON cw.website_id = cwd.website_id WHERE (cw.website_id != 0) GROUP BY `tp`.`entity_id`, `cg`.`customer_group_id`, `cw`.`website_id` ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `min_price` = VALUES(`min_price`)
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a script in your `html` directory, for example `programmatically_refresh_reindex.php`:

```
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
umask( 0 );
Mage :: app( "default" );
$ver = Mage :: getVersion();
$userModel = Mage :: getModel( 'admin/user' );
$userModel -> setUserId( 0 );
Mage :: getSingleton( 'admin/session' ) -> setUser( $userModel );

function refresh_cache() 
{    
    try {
        $allTypes = Mage::app()->useCache();
        foreach($allTypes as $type => $blah) {
          Mage::app()->getCacheInstance()->cleanType($type);
        }
      } catch (Exception $e) {
          echo $e->getMessage() . " <br>";
      }
    try{
        echo "<br>";
        $indexingProcesses = Mage::getSingleton('index/indexer')->getProcessesCollection(); 
        foreach ($indexingProcesses as $process) {
              $process->reindexEverything();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception $e){
        echo $e->getMessage() . " <br>";
    }
}

refresh_cache(); 
echo "<br>";  
echo "All cache types refreshed & all processes reindexed<br />";
```

See if Magento then managed to initialize the indexer by running the script by accessing `yourwebsite.com/programmatically_refresh_reindex.php` in a browser.

Let me know if this still fails.

Comment: I get this error: SQLSTATE[21S01]: Insert value list does not match column list: 1136 Column count doesn't match value count at row 1.
May it depend that for mistake I removed once the special_to_price from eav_attribute table and then restored it ?

Comment: It could definitely be related to that, you should check out this link: http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/db-repair-tool - it may be able to help you resolve things.

Comment: Did it. using a old database backup as a base. No effects sorted. It tells me that the db is not corrupted or something like that.

Comment: It's strange. The logs tell me about an error while indexing the tier prices but I never touched the tierprices. I'm importing the products using magmi.